# Hashmap holding a hashset - how to retrieve data

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

How do I obtain a list of all the objects that have the same value for a specific attribute out of `HashMap<String,HashSet<String>> objects` the String holds the attributes and the HashSet holds the list of values for the attributes!

Comment: Use an `Iterator` on the `HashSet`. A `Set` isn't really meant for retrieval, it's rather meant to check if something exists.

Comment: It would be *much* easier to help you if you'd give a concrete example.

Comment: the variable has been already defined for me. wasn't my choice! the hashmap contains a list of attributes e.g. `name`, `age` etc. and I want to retrieve all the objects which have the value `18` for `age` for example. I was imagining something like `objects.get("age").contains("18")` I hope I made it more clear now

Comment: though that does return me a boolean value... and I want the actual object where these values were found

Comment: can you provide a concrete example for the contents of the data?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Do you just have one object of type `HashMap<String,Set<String>>`, and you want to find all the keys in your `HashMap` that map to a set containing a particular value? Or you have a collection of objects that all have a field of type `HashMap<String,Set<String>>` and you want to find all the objects where, for example, the "age" key maps to a set containing the value "18"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,Set<String>> objects  = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
// fill it up

String needle = "value";
List<String> results = new LinkedList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String,Set<String>> entry : objects.entry set())
{
   if(entry.getValue().contains(needle))
   {
       results.add(entry.getKey());
   }
}
return results;
```